# Uncaught ReferenceError: Undefined parameter

Tags: javascript, parameters, arguments, undefined

I am getting an error for the following code.

```
function getDelAction(whatToDelete){
    return "<i class='fas fa-trash-alt text-danger' onclick=\"deleteRecord(this.closest('tr'), whatToDelete);\"></i>";
}
```

Created a function that returns a string representation of an element. When I run the code and click on the icon, JS complains about the `whatToDelete` argument I am passing to `deleteRecord` function which the function `getDelAction` is accepting as parameter. If I create the same variable outside the function and pass it like this it works. What is the problem?

Calling the function like `getDelAction("customer");`

Thanks!

Comment: Best to [avoid inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045), they have way too many problems to be worth using nowadays, such as a demented scope chain and quote escaping issues. Attach event listeners properly using Javascript with `addEventListener` instead.

Answer (score 0):

try to return the string using template literals so that whatToDelete is passed as a variable:

```
    return `<i class='fas fa-trash-alt text-danger' onclick=\"deleteRecord(this.closest('tr'),${whatToDelete});\"></i>`;
```

And like other people mentioned, try to avoid this sort of stuff